# Vertical-align middle for block inside div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble with vertical-align: center for `<p>` inside `<div>` . There is nothing more to explain so I just link JSfidle
[I'm JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BZGhU/9/)

## edit: please remember that there is `

```
.cover-price p{

    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .3);`
```

so there is a small blackbackground for price.

Comment: Isn't this the same question that you have posted -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584913/center-block-paragraph-inside-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added the "position:absolute;" attribute-value to the css sheet along with a "margin-top:170px; (which effects 170 in relation to the imaged div)

```
.cover-price{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    *position:absolute;*
}
.cover-price p{
    margin: auto 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    color: white;
    *margin-top:170px;*
}
```

let me know if this helps at all. This is, of course, placing the $20.00 in the middle of the image (i just hope that's what you want).

Comment: btw, I would not use line height because the area of the <p> would remain in the top even though the "$20.00" visible value would be down. using margins usually provides lesser worries for future considerations in layout designing compared to line height.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: table;` to your main div and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` to your p

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BZGhU/5/)