# Center block (paragraph) inside div

Tags: html, css, alignment

There is example in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZGhU/9/) .

Small description: `Div` is `300x300` but might be 500x500 or 100x100 in future (so need flexible solution) with `background image` (which is `size:cover` so don't care about size).

Inside this `div` there is `<p>` with hight of 50px (but might be 100px or 25px in future) which has text inside (20) and `background-color` that is a bit transparent (blue).

I want to center it inside this `div` and sollution should be flexible (so for future changes it won't be take a few hours to fix all images/ideas manually, so it would be cool to use `%` values.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
.cover-price{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position:relative; /*Make container relative*/
}

.cover-price p{
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(43,32,122, .3);
    color: pink;
    position:absolute; /*make P absolute*/
    top: calc(50% - 50px); /*give top as 50% - height of p*/
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WMUH/)**

*Using calc since you have specified css3 in tags*

If not using calc for lack of support below IE9 the you can specify the top value as `height of the container/2-height of para` i.e here `top: 100px;`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` to your cover price class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Span and normal padding??

```
<p><span class="price">20.0 </span></p>

.cover-price p{
line-height: 50px;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
/*background-color: rgba(43,32,122, .3);*/
color: pink;
padding-top : 45%;
position: relative;
}

.price{
background-color: rgba(43,32,122, .3);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BZGhU/13/

Answer (score 0):

```
    .cover-price{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;
}
```